# 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, google-chrome, whatsapp

In my python code, I have to use the path of chromedriver. I am sure about the path of chromedriver, but it does not work.

Is it possible that chromedriver does not install correctly? How can I understand it? I can see its icone at the related folder

Is it possible that I have another (main) chromedriver on my laptop? How can I check it?

This is the code:

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/chromedriverfolder')
```

And the error is:

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/chromedriverfolder') 
   File "/home/kouhi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
   self.service.start()
   File "/home/kouhi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:  'chromedriverfolder' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Did you check the `chromedriver.exe` permissions?

Comment: The fact that you're referencing this exe from python code is not enough to make it a programming question. Please delete your question and repost it on superuser.com

Comment: @ALFA   How can I check it?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  I am not sure if it is not programming question. Give me time to be sure about it. Thanks

Comment: @ReihanehKouhi can you run your script with sudo command? I think that the problem is the permissions.

Comment: ‘ls -l /home/kouhi/kouhi-company/chromedriverfolder’ will show the permissions.

Comment: @JaviGonzalez  Actually, I do not know how to run the script with sudo command. So I did these:  sudo myscript.sh -> sudo: myscript.sh: command not found.   Then I tried this: sudo -u kouhi command  --> sudo: command: command not found.

Comment: @paul41 thanks alot. The result is like this:   -rwxr-xr-x 1 kouhi kouhi 6932128 oct 21  2016 chromedriver
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kouhi kouhi 3141794 may    21 03:41 chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: Your permissions look the same as mine so that should be ok. You are logged in using the kouhi user correct? (I'm assuming yes, but just to be sure)

Comment: @paul41  yes.   Is it possible that I have another (main) chromedriver on my laptop? How can I check it?

Comment: `locate chromedriver` will find all the chromedrivers you have and show the location

Comment: Which version of Chrome do you have installed and which version of chromedriver did you get? Maybe those aren't matching up.

Comment: Thanks to all. Apparently the versions were different. After install everything again, it solved. Thank you all very much.